# How to get div of html to pdf with selectable text and preserved CSS?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to build a resume builder using React. I want the user to get the PDF version of their resume by clicking the download button but I don't know how to achieve that.

I had tried [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) and it is converting the editor `div` to PDF but not preserving CSS.

I had also tried jsPDF with [html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas) and it is converting the `div` to PDF with preserved CSS, but that PDF is made of images which means the text is not selectable and links are not clickable.

I am able to get PDF with selectable texts and preserved CSS when opening print dialogue box and saving as PDF, but I want a one-click solution. I don't want my user to perform extra efforts.

How can I save my `div` and its styles as a functional PDF? Alternatively, how can I use the browser's save as PDF function in a single click?

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364212/limit-print-area-to-a-div)

Comment: I know how to focus on particular div for printing and i am also able to achieve when opening print dialogue box and saving it as pdf from there. But I want a button clickable solution

Comment: These links might be helpful: https://www.adobe.com/bg/acrobat/how-to/convert-html-to-pdf.html
https://wkhtmltopdf.org/
https://www.evopdf.com/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIq4Pww77h9AIVuRkGAB3GTg5jEAAYASAAEgKBSvD_BwE

Comment: Its of no use as i want my user to get these service .

Comment: have you ever find a sollution?